# Suppose $U$ is connected and $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies $Du = 0$ a.e. in $U$. Prove $u$ is constant a.e. in $U.$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

***Sketch:*** Consider the domain $$U_\epsilon=\{x\in U : \mbox{dist}{(x,\partial U)}>\epsilon\}$$.
For $x\in U_\epsilon$ consider the function $$u_\epsilon(x)=\int_U \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y)\,dy$$ is a
standard mollifier. Then $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(U_\epsilon)$ and
$$Du_\epsilon(x)=\int_U\eta_\epsilon(x-y)Du(y)\,dy$$
by the definition of the weak derivative. Since $Du=0$ a.e., we have that $Du_\epsilon(x)=0$ for all $x\in U_\epsilon$ and hence $u_\epsilon$ is constant in $U_\epsilon$. Since $\|u_\epsilon−u\|_{L^p(U_\epsilon)}\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, we have that $u$ is constant a.e.

***Observations:*** This demostration uses some results and notation from the text Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition.

***Definitions:*** **(i)** Define $\eta\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by
$$\eta(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}C\exp\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right), & \mbox{if }|x|<1\\0, & \mbox{if } |x|\geq 1\end{array}\right.$$
the constant $C>0$  selected so that $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}}\eta\,dx=1$.

**(ii)** For each $\epsilon>0$, set $$\eta_\epsilon(x):=\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\eta\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right).$$

We call $\eta$ standard mollifier. The functions $\eta_\epsilon$ are $C^\infty$ and satisfy $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta_\epsilon\,dx=1, \mbox{spt}(\eta_\epsilon)\subset B(0,\epsilon).$$
spt denotes support.

It should be noted that this exercise has already been posted several times, but I am particularly focused on the demonstration whose outline is shown.

My questions are the following:

***1. Is $U_\epsilon$ really a domain?***

***2. By definition $Du=0$ a.e, implies that the gradient vector of u is equal to zero, except in a set of measure zero, then in the next line, it is stated that***

***Since $Du=0$ a.e., we have that $Du_\epsilon(x)=0$ for all $x\in U_\epsilon$ and hence $u_\epsilon$ is constant in $U_\epsilon$.***

therefore, for this to be true, $U_\epsilon$ must have a nonzero measure. ***How could I prove such a thing?***

3. I do not understand why "***Since $\|u_\epsilon−u\|_{L^p(U_\epsilon)}\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, we have that $u$ is constant a.e.***"

Comment: For (1) show that $U_{\epsilon}$ is an open subset of $U$.

Comment: For question (2), you are missing an important point: $u_{\epsilon}$ is smooth on $U_{\epsilon}$ (and this is the motivation behind mollifying $u$ in the first place). So, both $u_{\epsilon}$ and $Du_{\epsilon}$ are continuous. No need to negligible sets.